# How do I enable the serial port on an XServe G5 (10.4 Server)

Tags: router, mac-osx-server, xserve, serial

I have my ZyXel USG 200 router's console port connected to my XServe, and I want to stream real-time logs from it to a text file on the XServe itself.

I need the serial port to be set to 115200bps, N,8,1, no flow-control.

The OS in place is Mac OS X 10.4.11 Server.

Where do I make the adjustments to enable the on-board serial port with those settings?